# Try-catch affecting performance in XNA

Tags: c#, exception, xna, try-catch, sqrt

I'm struggling a bit with a try-catch behaviour. I've read that it can affect performance, but not as much as this block of code does to my machine.

```
foreach (Crew CurrentBall in CrewList)
            {
                if (CurrentBall != WhiteBall)
                {
                    double distance = 0;

                    try
                    {
                        distance = Math.Sqrt((CurrentBall.Rectangle.X - SnakeArray[CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1].Rectangle.X)
                            * (CurrentBall.Rectangle.X - SnakeArray[CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1].Rectangle.X)
                            + (CurrentBall.Rectangle.Y - SnakeArray[CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1].Rectangle.Y)
                            * (CurrentBall.Rectangle.Y - SnakeArray[CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1].Rectangle.Y));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        distance = Math.Sqrt((CurrentBall.Rectangle.X - WhiteBall.Rectangle.X)
                            * (CurrentBall.Rectangle.X - WhiteBall.Rectangle.X)
                            + (CurrentBall.Rectangle.Y - WhiteBall.Rectangle.Y)
                            * (CurrentBall.Rectangle.Y - WhiteBall.Rectangle.Y));
                    }

                    if (distance < 75 && CurrentBall != WhiteBall)
                    {
                        if (CurrentBall.IsFollowingWhite == false)
                        {
                            NumberOfBallsFollowingWhite++;
                            CrewCatch.Play();
                            Score += 5;
                            ReduceMovementSpeed();
                            ApplyText(CurrentBall);
                            SnakeArray[NumberOfBallsFollowingWhite] = CurrentBall;
                            CurrentBall.SnakePosition = NumberOfBallsFollowingWhite;
                        }

                        CurrentBall.Follow(SnakeArray[CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1]);
                        CurrentBall.IsFollowingWhite = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

It worked quite well until I used try-catch. I also tried without Math.Sqrt but it was no improvement.

Comment: The most expensive part of the try/catch block is actual the catching (throwing, stacktrace etc.). I think an `if/else` would be better suited in your case.

Comment: You should sanitize the inputs, don't rely on a catch to perform different logic.

Comment: Why are you using try/catch? That mechanism should NEVER EVER be used in games.

Comment: `It worked quite well until I used try-catch. I also tried without Math.Sqrt but it was no improvement.` I think you already answerd your own question  XD

Comment: Where are you throwing the exceptions? Stop throwing exceptions like crazy. @Stefan Good one, made me lol

Comment: It's in the name: an exception should only be used when something *exceptional* has happened. If it's part of normal operation, an exception is not what you want. If you can predict ahead of time whether an exception will be thrown, then do so, and do something to avoid it. An exception is your code's way of saying "I'm sorry, there's absolutely nothing I can do to make this work, someone else please take over".

Comment: **Tip**: You should get into the habit of using `Vector2` for storing **position** information rather than using the position from your `bounds`.  Then there is no mucking about with `x` and `y` and thus halves your code because you'll be using vector math

Answer (score 3):

This whole thing:

```
try
{
    distance = Math.Sqrt((CurrentBall.Rectangle.X - SnakeArray[CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1].Rectangle.X)
        * (CurrentBall.Rectangle.X - SnakeArray[CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1].Rectangle.X)
        + (CurrentBall.Rectangle.Y - SnakeArray[CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1].Rectangle.Y)
        * (CurrentBall.Rectangle.Y - SnakeArray[CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1].Rectangle.Y));
}
catch
{
    distance = Math.Sqrt((CurrentBall.Rectangle.X - WhiteBall.Rectangle.X)
        * (CurrentBall.Rectangle.X - WhiteBall.Rectangle.X)
        + (CurrentBall.Rectangle.Y - WhiteBall.Rectangle.Y)
        * (CurrentBall.Rectangle.Y - WhiteBall.Rectangle.Y));
}
```

Could be reduced to something like:

```
if (CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1 >= 0 && CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1 < SnakeArray.Length)
{
    int xValue = CurrentBall.Rectangle.X - SnakeArray[CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1].Rectangle.X; 
    int xSquared = xValue * xValue;

    int yValue = CurrentBall.Rectangle.Y - SnakeArray[CurrentBall.SnakePosition - 1].Rectangle.Y;
    int ySquared = yValue * yValue;

    distance = Math.Sqrt(xSquared + ySquared);
}
else
{
    //And similar for the above here...
    distance = Math.Sqrt((CurrentBall.Rectangle.X - WhiteBall.Rectangle.X)
                            * (CurrentBall.Rectangle.X - WhiteBall.Rectangle.X)
                            + (CurrentBall.Rectangle.Y - WhiteBall.Rectangle.Y)
                            * (CurrentBall.Rectangle.Y - WhiteBall.Rectangle.Y));
}
```

Never use a try/catch to perform logic operations. Also never `Catch` if you don't do something with the exception.

Also try to make your logic easy to read. See what I did in the first part of the "if"? See how much easier it is to understand (and debug). And no performance loss, the compiler will optimize it out!

Comment: _"Also **never Catch** if you don't do something with the exception"_ - generally true but not always the case. There are times when you want to swallow it. e.g. [add-in managers and partial trust](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163701.aspx)

Comment: Even then, if you are catching it, you should at least log or trace it. It excepted for a reason. To be honest though, I have swallowed exceptions before but I always felt dirty doing it :)